# Python Selenium: Finding elements by xpath when there are duplicates in the html code

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

So I'm working in selenium to scrape content from a liqour sales website in order to more quickly add product details to a spreadsheet. I'm using selenium to log into the website and search for the correct product. Once I get to the product page I'm able to scrape all the data I need except for some data that's contained in a certain block of the code.

I'm wanting 3 pieces of data: price per case, price per bottle, and price per oz. I noticed in the code that the data I'm looking for appears twice in a similar pattern. Interestingly, the correct data that I want is the second occurrence of the data (the first occurrence is incorrect). The relevant HTML code is:

```html
<h2>Pricing</h2>

  <div id="prices-table">
      

    

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-condensed auto-width">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>

          <th class="best-bottle-top">
            Frontline
          </th>

      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

      <tr>
        <td>Bottles</td>

          <td class="best-bottle-mid">1</td>

      </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Cases</td>

            <td class="best-bottle-mid">—</td>

        </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Price per bottle</td>
          <td class="best-bottle-mid">
            <div>$16.14   #I don't want this data </div>
          </td>

      </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Price per case</td>

            <td class="best-bottle-mid">
              <div>
                $193.71   #I don't want this data
              </div>
            </td>
        </tr>



        <tr>
          <td>Cost per ounce</td>

            <td class="best-bottle-mid">
              <div>$1.27   #I don't want this data </div>

            </td>

        </tr>

      <tr>
        <td></td>

            <td class="best-bottle-bot text-muted">
              <span class="best-bottle-bot-content">

                <span>
                  <div><small>Best</small></div>
                  <small>Bottle</small>
                </span>
              </span>
            </td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>





  <p>
    <em class="price-disclaimer">Defer to Athens Distributing Company of Tennessee in case of any price discrepancies.</em>
  </p>



  </div>

            </div>
            <hr class="visible-print-block">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="3400355">
              <dl class="dl-horizontal vpv-row">
  <dt>Sizing</dt><dd>750 mL bottle × 6</dd>
        <dt>SKU</dt><dd>80914</dd>
  <dt>UPC</dt><dd>853192006189</dd>
  <dt>Status</dt><dd>Active</dd>
  
  
  
  <dt>Availability</dt><dd>
      <span class="label label-success inventory-status-badge"><span data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Athens Distributing Company of Tennessee is integrated with SevenFifty and sends inventory levels at least once a day. You can order this item and expect that it is available." data-original-title="" title="">IN STOCK</span></span>
</dd></dl>




  <div id="prices-table">
      

    

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-condensed auto-width">
    <h2>Pricing</h2><thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>

          <th class="best-bottle-top">
            Frontline
          </th>

      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

      <tr>
        <td>Bottles</td>

          <td class="best-bottle-mid">1</td>

      </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Cases</td>

            <td class="best-bottle-mid">—</td>

        </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Price per bottle</td>
          <td class="best-bottle-mid">
            <div>$33.03   #I want THIS data </div>
          </td>

      </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Price per case</td>

            <td class="best-bottle-mid">
              <div>
                $198.18   I want THIS data
              </div>
            </td>
        </tr>



        <tr>
          <td>Cost per ounce</td>

            <td class="best-bottle-mid">
              <div>$1.30   I want THIS data </div>

            </td>

        </tr>

      <tr>
        <td></td>

            <td class="best-bottle-bot text-muted">
              <span class="best-bottle-bot-content">

                <span>
                  <div><small>Best</small></div>
                  <small>Bottle</small>
                </span>
              </span>
            </td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Using the full xpath chrome give me finds me what I want, but trying a relative path does not work. Here's what I've tried:

Full xpath for case price (works but don't want to use absolute references):

```
/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/div
```

Relative xpath for case price (returns None):

```
//*[@id="prices-table"]/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/div
```

Unfortunately I can't link the actual webpage because it requires login credentials. Thanks for any/all help.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to do it.

1. If everything is same, tags their attribute then use xpath indexing.

   ```
   //td[text()='Price per bottle']/following-sibling::td[@class='best-bottle-mid']
   ```

This represent **two nodes**, using `find_element` will only work with first occurrence which you do not want. So you can do this :

```
(//td[text()='Price per bottle']/following-sibling::td[@class='best-bottle-mid'])[2]
```

to locate the second web element. Similarly you can do for `Price per case` and
`Cost per ounce`

2. The other way would be to use `find_elements`

   ```
   price_per_bottle_elements  = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//td[text()='Price per bottle']/following-sibling::td[@class='best-bottle-mid']")

   print(price_per_bottle_elements[0].text) # this we do not want. 

   print(price_per_bottle_elements[1].text) # this we want.
   ```